# how to make API for comments on a blog detail view. I don't need replies to comments ( i.e. no children comment)

Tags: python, django, model

I want to show comments of a blog post detail. I am new to Django. I have to make an API for this. Here is what I have:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('travel_news', 'Travel News',),
        ('travel_tips', 'Travel Tips',),
        ('things_to_do', 'Things to Do',),
        ('places_to_go', 'Places to Go'),
    )
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='travel_news')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    
    # todo support for tags
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='#travel') #todo
    date_created = models.DateField()

    @property
    def html_stripped(self):
       from django.utils.html import strip_tags
       return strip_tags(self.content)

  
class Comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)
```

This is my serializers

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    blog = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'


 
class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    comments = CommentSerializer(source='comments.content')
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['image', 'categories', 'description', 'content', 'tags', 'date_created', 'comments']
        # fields = '__all__'
```

Here is my view.

```
class BlogPostDetailsListAPIView(ListAPIView):
       
        serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer

        def get_queryset(self):
            return BlogPost.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Here my view is returning only the BLogpost objects, but not comments.How to return the comments along with the post detail view as well? Can we do without the contenttype?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this recently. In your BlogSerializer, you could change from `CommentSerializer(source='comments.content')` to `CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`.

I am new to Restframework so dont really understand how thing does.

Comment: But, I have returned only Blogpost object on my view. How can I returned comments objects as well??

Comment: Did you changed as above, what did you get? In my case I got an array of comment object as property of blogpost object